# Adding HttpPost getting error 'The Resource Cannot Be Found' in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm getting the error 
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ClientEdit/ClientEdit/1104

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

when I add HttpPost attribute to a controller.  I've looked into this and corrected my code with posted(no pun intended) answers but nothing I've tried works.  Here's my controller header:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClientEdit(int id,FormCollection formCollection)
```

I added HttpPost so I can populate my FormCollection object.  As with other SO posts, this causes the error. Removing it solves the issue but my FormCollection doesn't populate any key/value pairs.

My view has its form tag's method set to POST which solved other dev's issues but it doesn't solve mine.  I tried adding 'name=' properties to my textbox controls as well as 'id=' but that doesn't work either.

```
<body>

<form method="post" action="1104" id="form1">
```

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: @Charls point was valid, just posted in the wrong place. Please edit your question to include the actual exception you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide you view that renders the `<form>` as well. The `action` on what you show as your HTML looks wrong to me. I would think it would be something like `action="/Controller/ClientEdit"`.

Answer (score 0):

you have given wrong value in the attribute action="1104".

Either you can specify proper route in action attribute or leave it if the route is same as of get.

This should work if GET and POST route are same

```
<form method="post"  id="form1">
.....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
<!--Your form field-->
}
```

Basically what is happening is that your action attribute is just pointing to the Id you have and not the url to post to.

You can do it manually like this:

```
<form action="ClientEdit/ClientEdit/1104>
<!--form fields-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are all correct.  I was passing a userid as the action.  This was legacy code that 'worked' for another feature but doesn't conform to the MVC pattern.  I did some other research (as I'm not too familiar with MVC either) and started again from scratch using MVC as it should be.  Thanks everyone.